# Standard practice of workaround to extend 2 classes in Java

Tags: java, design-patterns

This is the scenario

```
interface BaseMsg
interface SpecialMsg

class FooBaseMsg implements BaseMsg
class FooSpecialMsg extends FooBaseMsg implements SpecialMsg

// The above classes are written by another team, and cannot be modified. 

class BarBaseMsg implements BaseMsg // totally different way to implement
class BarSpecialMsg // this is the question
```

Methods implemented for `SpecialMsg` in `FooSpecialMsg` is totally the same as in `BarSpecialMsg`.

So it is really bad practice to copy-paste the implementations

But methods for `BaseMsg` is different.

My current approach is

```
class BarSpecialMsg extends BarBaseMsg implements SpecialMsg
  private FooSpecialMsg foo;
  // constructors will have super(), and initialize FooSpecialMsg
  // implements methods from SpecialMsg by calling
  // foo.methods()
```

Is this the correct way to do it? What are the standards for this kind of problem?

Is there some sort of design pattern to counter this?

The down-side of current approach is that the data is duplicated since it uses resources for 2 objects for every usage

Comment: Depending upon how you look at it, you have a `Decorator` or a `Adapter` pattern implemented using Composition. This approach is perfectly reasonable.

Comment: If you can't extend, decorate. So this is correct, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this the correct way to do it? What are the standards for this kind
>   of problem?
>
> Is there some sort of design pattern to counter this?

You use composition to share a common behavior.
It is a valid approach.
In fact you already use a design pattern : the adapter or wrapper.

`BarSpecialMsg` is the adapter class and `FooSpecialMsg` is the adaptee class.
Or from the wrapper pattern point of view, `BarSpecialMsg` is the wrapper class and `FooSpecialMsg` is the wrapped class.

> Methods implemented for SpecialMsg in FooSpecialMsg is totally the
>   same as in BarSpecialMsg.
>
> But methods for BaseMsg is different

However, I don't see the advantage to couple `FooSpecialMsg` to `BarSpecialMsg`.

If the methods defined in `FooSpecialMsg` to implement the  `BaseMsg` interface should not used by `BarSpecialMsg`, I think that composing `BarSpecialMsg` with `FooSpecialMsg` could be error-prone. Besides, it creates a coupling between two implementations that is really not required.

In this case, defining a common class implementing `SpecialMsg` seems better.

```
public class CommonSpecialMsg implements SpecialMsg {...}
```

In this way, you could compose `FooSpecialMsg` and `BarSpecialMsg` with an instance of `CommonSpecialMsg` and delegate implementation of `SpecialMsg` to it  :

```
class BarSpecialMsg extends BarBaseMsg implements SpecialMsg {
  private CommonSpecialMsg composedSpecialMsg;
 ...
}

class FooSpecialMsg extends BarBaseMsg implements SpecialMsg {
  private CommonSpecialMsg composedSpecialMsg;
 ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. I totally agree with that. But as I mentioned, `BarSpecialMsg` is written by another team, and they are very clear that their code is not to be touched. I will bring up this issue when I meet with them.

Comment: Arg, it was written in a Java comment, I didn't see it...  In fact I never read comments ;-) I understand that the code is written by another team but in this case, your solution is acceptable. A little improvement would be to declare  in the `BarSpecialMsg` class :  `private SpecialMsg foo;`instead of    `private FooSpecialMsg foo;` and to provide a constructor with the same logic : `public BarSpecialMsg(SpecialMsg specialMsg)`. It would add more abstraction and prevent bad use of the specific implementation : `FooSpecialMsg`.

Comment: Yes, I forgot about the abstraction. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: You are welcome. I forgot. I didn't answer to your question but you use already a design Pattern : the adapter. I edited my answer.